# Existence and uniqueness of a subfield of an algebraic closure of a certain degree over a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Currently, I am reading [Rohrlich's article "Elliptic Curves and the Weil-Deligne Group"](https://math.berkeley.edu/~dyott/Elliptic%20Curves%20and%20the%20Weil-Deligne%20Group.pdf) and got stuck in the beginning already.

Namely, let $k$ be a finite field of characteristic $p$ and cardinality $q$ and let $\bar{k}$ denote an algebraic closure of $k$. Then it is said that for an positive integer $n$ then there is a unique subfield $k_n$ of $\bar{k}$ of degree $n$ over $k$.

Could you explain me why it exists and why this is a unique subfield? Thank you.

Comment: By basic results on finite fields the elements of $k_n$ are zeros of $x^{q^n}-x$. This polynomial has exactly $q^n$ zeros  in $\overline{k}$, so $k_n$ gets specified as a subset.

Comment: Do the answers/discussion e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1108826/11619) give enough details? Sorry if I sound a bit "less than enthusiastic". We have just covered this theme from so many angles so many times :-)