# Finite extension of the inclusion $\mathbb F_p \to \Omega$ is injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\Omega$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$ and $\mathbb F_p \to \Omega$ be the standard inclusion map. I wonder if for any finite extension $K/{\mathbb F_p}$, the extension of this inclusion to $K \to \Omega$ is still injective (the existence of the extension is given by the Zorn's lemma,see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1109145/185631) for a proof).

To avoid the cyclic reasoning, I hope the solution doesn't use the fact that any two finite fields of the same cardinality are isomorphic.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something in your question, but any ring homomorphism between two fields is necessarily injective

Comment: @Dave Okay... what a stupid question....

Comment: Don't worry we all have them now and then, I once asked for a proof of a result and it turned out that intersecting two lines gave a counterexample...